# LS2J throws java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Java Error when use Apache POI XSSF

Tags: apache-poi, lotus-domino, ls2j

I would like to do Excel Export in the file format of XLSX. I have chosen Apache POI OOXML 3.9 (without excel installed on server). I see Excel export with the file format xls (HSSF) works well with LS2J. But XSSF not works.

I am using following Jar 
1) poi
2) poi-ooxml
3) dom4j
4) poi--ooxml-schemas
5) XML beans

I have existing business logic which is written in lotus script, so i want to expose Excel export(Java) via LS2J. But i keep getting following error

**Threw java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**

Source code:-
package com.clr.oocmlexcel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelWriter {

```
public boolean writeExcelHeader(Object rowValues) {
    try {
         XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\temp\\howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));
           workbook.write(out);
           out.close();


        return true;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

        return(false);  
    }

}
```

}

Lotus Agent code:-
Option Public
Option Declare
UseLSX "*javacon"

Use "OOOXMLExcelWriter"

Sub Initialize
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim js As JAVASESSION
    Dim xlWriterClass As JAVACLASS
    Dim xlWriterObject As JavaObject

```
Set js = New JAVASESSION
Set xlWriterClass = js.GetClass("com.clr.oocmlexcel.ExcelWriter")
Set xlWriterObject = xlWriterClass.CreateObject
If(Not(xlWriterObject.writeExcelHeader()))Then
    Print "Error creating excel sheet!"
    Exit Sub        
End If
```

End Sub

When i try to use the same functionality with Java Agent i able to achieve but LS2J not helps.

Can you please help me someone?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code and stacktrace.

Comment: POI 3.9 is several years old, why are you using an old version?

Comment: Even with POI 3.11 i am getting same error. Here i am just creating workbook and save and even simple functionality not works

Comment: This code work when i move the POI jar into '\jvm\lib\ext'. yet to explore why its work with jar in db itself